# Identifying the houses robbed in the maximize profits puzzle

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I am attempting the 'Smart thief' problem, where we have an list of neighboring house values and the aim is to maximize profits. The one restriction is that once a house is robbed, the houses left or right to it cannot be robbed. I have managed to find out what the maximum value of the loot can be with the following code :

```
def max_theft(house_val, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return house_val[0]
    if n == 2:
        return max(house_val[0], house_val[1])


    max_theft_val = [0]*n


    max_theft_val[0] = house_val[0]
    max_theft_val[1] = max(house_val[0], house_val[1])


    for i in range(2, n):
        max_theft_val[i] = max(house_val[i]+max_theft_val[i-2],   max_theft_val[i-1])

    return max_theft_val
```

However, the next part of the problem would be to identify which houses make up for this summation. Is there a way to figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way. Notice when a house is chosen and add it to a list. If the next chosen house is less than two houses ahead replace the last house in the list; otherwise, add it.

JavaScript code (sorry, on smartphone, but this should be easy to adapt):

```js
function max_theft(house_val, n){
  if (n == 0)
    return 0
  if (n == 1)
    return house_val[0]
  if (n == 2)
    return Math.max(house_val[0], house_val[1])

  let max_theft_val = new Array(n).fill(0)
    
  let chosen = [house_val[0]]
    
  function add_house(i){
    if (i - chosen[ chosen.length-1 ] < 2)
      chosen[ chosen.length-1 ] = i
    else
      chosen.push(i)
  }
    
  max_theft_val[0] = house_val[0]

  let a = house_val[0]
  let b = house_val[1]

  if (a > b){
    console.log(`Choosing house 0`)
    max_theft_val[1] = a
    add_house(0)
        
  } else {
    console.log(`Choosing house 1`)
    max_theft_val[1] = b
    add_house(1)
  }

  for (let i=2; i<n; i++){
    let a = house_val[i] + max_theft_val[i-2]
    let b = max_theft_val[i-1]
      
    if (a > b){
      console.log(`Choosing house ${i}`)
      max_theft_val[i] = a
      add_house(i)
        
    } else {
      console.log(`Choosing prev best ${i-1}`)
      max_theft_val[i] = b
    }
  }

  console.log(`Chosen ${chosen}`)
  return max_theft_val[n-1]
}

var arr = [1,4,3,40,50]

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
console.log(max_theft(arr, arr.length))
```